# Keras Transfer Learning Issue

Tags: keras, neural-network, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I have trained & saved a smaller network on my small dataset, and I want to use transfer learning.

I want to use this saved network on top of the conv part of the pretrained VGG16, specifically I want to freeze some layers of VGG but not all then I want to use the fc that I have already trained on my smaller dataset, and learn a model which is a combination of both with transferred weights.

I am following a mish and mash of tutorials: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html and https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-to-classify-photos-of-dogs-and-cats/ I do not just want to use pretrained features, and I do not just want to add two new layers to the VGG's conv net, as I mentioned, I want to transfer the fc layers of the smaller network and freeze all blocks of conv layers but one of VGGs and train again. Below is my code but I get an error (no matter how I tried to change around the code, I get a similar error)

```
from keras import applications
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense

# path to the model weights files.
weights_path = '/home/d/Desktop/s/vgg16_weights.h5'
top_model_weights_path = '/home/d/Desktop/s/model_weights.h5'
# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 256, 256

# build the VGG16 network
base_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(256, 256, 3))
print('Model loaded.')

# set the first 25 layers (up to the last conv block)
# to non-trainable (weights will not be updated)
for layer in base_model.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False

# build a classifier model to put on top of the convolutional model
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


# note that it is necessary to start with a fully-trained
# classifier, including the top classifier,
# in order to successfully do fine-tuning
top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)

model= Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=top_model(base_model.output))



# add the model on top of the convolutional base
#model.add(top_model)


print(top_model.summary())

# compile the model with a SGD/momentum optimizer
# and a very slow learning rate.
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"

train_dir = '/home/d/Desktop/s/data/train'
eval_dir = '/home/d/Desktop/s/data/eval'
test_dir = '/home/d/Desktop/s/data/test'



# create a data generator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,   #Scale the image between 0 and 1
                                    rotation_range=40,
                                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                                    shear_range=0.2,
                                    zoom_range=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip=True,)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  #We do not augment validation data. we only perform rescale

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  #We do not augment validation data. we only perform rescale

# load and iterate training dataset
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, class_mode='binary', batch_size=16, shuffle='True', seed=42)
# load and iterate validation dataset
val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(eval_dir, class_mode='binary', batch_size=16, shuffle='True', seed=42)
# load and iterate test dataset
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir, class_mode=None, batch_size=1, shuffle='False', seed=42)

#The training part
#We train for 64 epochs with about 100 steps per epoch
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size,
                              epochs=6,
                              validation_data=val_generator,
                              validation_steps=val_generator.n // val_generator.batch_size)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Model loaded.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d/Desktop/s/transferLearningS.py", line 33, in <module>
    top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1166, in load_weights
    f, self.layers, reshape=reshape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 1030, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    str(len(filtered_layers)) + ' layers.')
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 6 layers into a model with 2 layers.
```

And my smaller network is built this way:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))  #Dropout for regularization
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  #Sigmoid function at the end because we have just two classes
```

Any recommendations how I can fix this issue?

Comment: How about `top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path, skip_mismatch=True, by_name=True)`

Comment: Well, you will get something like `A tensor is not element of this graph` later though

Comment: Does this only skip the name mismatch? or does it just bypass warnings? How can I be sure that the weights are transferred correctly?

Comment: This will load the weights by each layer's name and skip the name that not in the weights file or the model. It will just error later because it's `Dense(512)` below and `Dense(256)` above.

Comment: More importantly, it's gonna error again when you create the model since there are 2 models for input and output each and they don't connect.

Comment: Just use `VGG` from the beginning. The real problem is, this is not how you do the transfer learning. If you trained it with another feature extractor architecture then it's not gonna be any different when you transfer it to `VGG` compare to train VGG from scratch.

Comment: I wanted to do this particularly because creator of Keras noted: in order to perform fine-tuning, all layers should start with properly trained weights: for instance you should not slap a randomly initialized fully-connected network on top of a pre-trained convolutional base. This is because the large gradient updates triggered by the randomly initialized weights would wreck the learned weights in the convolutional base. In our case this is why we first train the top-level classifier, and only then start fine-tuning convolutional weights alongside it.

Comment: From here: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: Nonono, what he means is like what I said. Just freeze the VGG's feature extractor and train only `Dense` layers from the start. Think about it carefully, if you train it somewhere else and then move to VGG, it wouldn't be any different from using VGG in the first place right? Since the output value from the last feature extractor won't equal anyway.

Comment: Transfer Learning is, use feature extractor that already fine-tuned on a large dataset and train the `Dense` on your desired dataset.

Comment: I am sorry I totally understand it the other way still, have you checked the website for the full reference? He says: why we first train the top-level classifier, and only then start fine-tuning convolutional weights alongside it.

Comment: Or do I freeze all conv, train fc on vgg top, then train once more with the last conv layer set to trainable?

Comment: This whole concept was more clear with caffe doing net surgery

Comment: OK, you need to understand that the word `top-level classifier` means the `Dense` layers, not the `Convolutions`. What he means there is, `if you have a fine-tuned weights, then load the feature extractor to the newly-created model for your new task, train only the Dense layers first because high loss when you start train the random-init weights might makes the Conv layers weight changed too much, after a while then unfreeze them and train all of them together to maximizer the preformance`.

Comment: When you call `VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)`, the `weights='imagenet'` part means that the model will load the fine-tuned weights that trained on Imagenet dataset, `include_top=False` means that the model will not has the `top` layers, so you can put `Dense` to it later